# How to access columns of joined SQL table (for JSON)

Tags: php, sql, json

On my PHP file, I am running the following SQL query:

```
SELECT *   
FROM national_age_gender_demographics INNER JOIN arizona_age_gender_demographics
WHERE national_age_gender_demographics.age_group = arizona_age_gender_demographics.age_group
ORDER BY national_age_gender_demographics.index_number";
```

Now, I am trying to access the rows to create JSON data using the following:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $numRows; $i++) {
    if ($i != 0) {
        $tableData .= ",[";
    }
    $tableData .= '"' . $row['national_age_gender_demographics.age_group'] . '",';
    $tableData .= '"' . $row['national_age_gender_demographics.both_pop'] . '",';
    $tableData .= '"' . $row['national_age_gender_demographics.male_pop'] . '",';
    $tableData .= '"' . $row['national_age_gender_demographics.female_pop'] . '",';
    $tableData .= '"' . $row['national_age_gender_demographics.male_percent'] . '",';
    $tableData .= '"' . $row['national_age_gender_demographics.female_percent'] . '",';
    $tableData .= '"' . $row['national_age_gender_demographics.both_percent'] . '",';
    $tableData .= '"' . $row['national_age_gender_demographics.males_per_100_females'] . '",';
    $tableData .= '"' . $row['arizona_age_gender_demographics.both_pop'] . '",';
    $tableData .= '"' . $row['arizona_age_gender_demographics.male_pop'] . '",';
    $tableData .= '"' . $row['arizona_age_gender_demographics.female_pop'] . '",';
    $tableData .= '"' . $row['arizona_age_gender_demographics.male_percent'] . '",';
    $tableData .= '"' . $row['arizona_age_gender_demographics.female_percent'] . '",';
    $tableData .= '"' . $row['arizona_age_gender_demographics.both_percent'] . '",';
    $tableData .= '"' . $row['arizona_age_gender_demographics.males_per_100_females'] . '"]';
    if ($i != $numRows - 1) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    }
}
```

When entering the URL of the PHP file in my browser, I am getting undefined indices for each line I am trying to access the joined table.

I wonder, what is the proper syntax to access the joined table?  And no, don't tell me to use json_encode, since it throws a JavaScript error with DataTables.

Answer (score 0):

You cant have `.` in column names so i assume the first part is actually the name of the table. In which case you array keys are the part after the period:

```
$row['males_per_100_females']
```

If you are going to ouput the JSON you should jsut use `json_encode` instead of manually encoding it.

```
$data = array(
   'some_key' => 'some data',
   'table_data' => array()
);

while(false !== ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())) {
   $data['table_data'][] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Okay.  Looking at my errors now, it looks like the error I am getting is "Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 64 bytes) in C:\wamp\www\CensusDatabase\database_scripts\CombinedAgeGender.php on line 25".

Any way to get around this?

Comment: OK, I figured out my problem.  I had to do it line by line instead of all at once.  Here is my solution:
`if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
   echo '{"aaData":[';

    $first = true;
    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
        //  cast results to specific data types

        if($first) {
            $first = false;
        } else {
            echo ',';
        }
        echo json_encode($row);
    }
    echo ']}';
} else {
    echo '[]';
}`